# User agent etails - lookup based?

Tags: database, user-agent

When detecting user details like Browser name, OS name, versions, City (from IP address), screen resolution, Flash enabled, etc. are these text entries in the database or do we use lookups to FK them in the user log table? This table is the session details table for users who are signed in to my site.

Currently my team has these are varchars but I want it as FK IDs from a lookup list of values for each so I can perform detailed analytic, however I am not sure what works in the 'real world'?

Answer (score 0):

These details are by default logged in a log file. This log file has configurable format and you can do the configuration at your web server, Apache httpd, Tomcat or whatever you might use. If you want to analyze these details and mine data etc., you better parse the log file data and store the information into a database. Then you can do any analytics you like easier, using SQL.

Comment: Log file has details of all visitors but i am only logging details of registered users. I have non registered sections on my site so people can hang around without logging in but i do not need their data. Plus I am logging more details too like flash version, if session is user flagged etc which is beyond the log file.

Comment: I do not know about the flash version, but since you can read off the log file the full URL-requested and actions, you will be able to identify the sessions that have successfully logged into your application even from there. Your second option will be to get the information you want from the Session object and add it into a database by extending your business-logic a bit.